# Google API PHP client with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I made a WP plugin which depends on the Youtube API. So, to do it well, I use Google API PHP client.

My issue is quite simple: the Google API PHP client is huge (more than 12 000 files), including clients for all Google services, when I just need to use Youtube service. So I'm not confortable committing all those files to the WP plugins repo when most of them are useless in my case.

So, right now, my `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

Any way to use only the Youtube API client (using composer if it's possible)?

Comment: Won't be a way with Composer, I suspect. You could *conceivably* use something like Xdebug or Blackfire to figure out exactly which files your app's usage hits in Google's files and just include those.

Comment: Sure, this is what I've done. But this seems to be kinda messy to me.

Comment: It is indeed messy. It'd be nice if WordPress would start using Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not for the feign of heart but it is doable.

1. Go to this branch of the repo https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master
2. Grab the full `src/Google` directory you will need all of that.
3. In the `src/Google/Service` directory is the stuff for all the different APIs.  Remove everything except for YouTube.
4. cross your fingers it should work.

This wont remove all 12000 files but it should give you just what you absolutely need.  I used to do this but its been a few years.

Comment: At last, this is what I've done. Removing all in `src/Google/Service`except all related Youtube stuff. It works. I'm gonna open an issue on Github to ask about this feature.

Comment: Opened it : https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/1343

Comment: I dont know enough about composer but i wouldnt be surprised if there wasnt a way for them to package it per api.   The main problem i think will be to my knowledge they arent doing much development on the library these days.   I am not sure who is dealing with feature requests

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible without manually including the relevant files in your project (which is a really bad idea).

The reason why its impossible, is because Google places all service APIs for the PHP library in a single GitHub repository found here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services

If Google does split them into multiple repositories, then it could be possible to include a single repo.

For now, though, all services are under one composer project and one repo. Maybe its worth making a GitHub issue to ask Google about this?

Comment: That was the answer i feared. I'll open an issue about that soon I think. Thanks :)